# ASP.Net AjaxForm Table Sorting/Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I'm trying to create my table in asp.net mvc using ajax form.

My problem is that i don't know how to send my data to the server while in the ajax form for my sorting and paging.

My model have those property   Sort, ItemPerPage, CurrentPage, SearchText.

when i click on the navigation, the call to the server is working but i doesn't get any values in my model!!

```
var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,
    UpdateTargetId = "beer-search-result"
};

using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchBeer", "Beers", new { Area = "Brewery" }, ajaxOptions))
{
    <input type="text" id="Search" name="SearchText" class="form-control" placeholder="Recherche" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>

    @Ajax.Paging(Model, ajaxOptions)

    ... my grid ...
}
```

Here is my Paging Method:

```
    public static IHtmlString Paging(this AjaxHelper ajax, IPage page, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        var nav = new TagBuilder("nav");
        nav.MergeAttribute("aria-label", "Page navigation");

        var ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
        ul.AddCssClass("pagination");

        if (page.ShowPrevious())
        {
            ul.InnerHtml += PagingSpecial("&laquo;", "Previous");
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < page.NumberOfPages(); i++)
        {
            var li = new TagBuilder("li");
            var link = new TagBuilder("a");
            link.InnerHtml = (i + 1).ToString();
            link.MergeAttributes(ajaxOptions.ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes());

            if (i == page.CurrentPage)
            {
                li.AddCssClass("active");
            }

            li.InnerHtml += link;
            ul.InnerHtml += li;
        }

        if (page.ShowNext())
        {
            ul.InnerHtml += PagingSpecial("&raquo;", "Next");
        }

        nav.InnerHtml += ul;
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(nav.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }

    private static TagBuilder PagingSpecial(string text, string ariaText)
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");

        var link = new TagBuilder("a");
        link.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
        link.Attributes.Add("aria-label", ariaText);

        var span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.Attributes.Add("aria-hidden", "true");
        span.InnerHtml = text;

        link.InnerHtml += span;
        li.InnerHtml += link;

        return li;
    }
```

What do i need to add to my link so it send their value to the CurrentPage model value!

Comment: Unclear what you asking. Are you referring to the submit button or the links generated by your extension method? And what is `ajax` in `@Ajax.Paging(Model, ajax)` (you have not declared that anywhere)

Comment: the code for Paging is in the post, check the extensions method to ajaxhelper. my question is about how to send the data from the click on the link inside the paging extension

Comment: You still have not said what `ajax` is. If you model contains the properties, then you need to build the `href` attribute of the `<a>` elements to include the values as query string/route values.

Comment: ajax is ajaxOptions  error while copying, so i need to write ex:   ?Sort=""&SearchText=""&CurrentPage="3"    to my link ?

Comment: Yes. What is the actual html generated by the links (in particular the `href` attribute)?

Comment: It work that way, i added the href with query string 
here is the generated link :
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace-with" data-ajax-update="#beer-search-result" href="/Brewery/Beers/SearchBeer?Sort=TEST&amp;CurrentPage=3">4</a>

Comment: Since its reading the `href` attribute from the `Ajax.BeginForm()`, then you can just use `Ajax.BeginForm("SearchBeer", "Beers", new { Area = "Brewery", Sort = Model.Sort, CurrentPage = Model.CurrentPage })`

Comment: every parameter are dynamic (Paging will change CurrentPage, Sorting will change Sort, SearchTextbox will change SearchText), so is there a way to overide the value i will put in the routeValues object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125910/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-vince).